# "Did she know I'd been in a fight?"

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: Have you talked to her today?

B: Yes, she called me.

A: What did she say? **Did she know I'd been in a fight?** Is that why she doesn't want to talk to me?

The fight that A was in was three days ago.

Is the sentence in bold as natural as possible for the context or is it not clear that he's referring to that specific fight he was in three days ago?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are asking about dialogue in fiction. To answer your question requires knowing whether the speaker's character is such that fights would likely be frequent or infrequent, and whether the female character being referenced is likely to believe that the speaker gets in fights hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, annually, or less frequently.

If for example it is plausible in the fictional context that the speaker is known generally to have two or three fights a day, the sentence is hopelessly vague.

Then it might be preferable to say

> What did she say? Was she talking about a fight I had three days ago? Is that ancient history why she doesn't want to talk to me?

But if the speaker and the woman are both devout pacifists, then it might be preferable to say

> What did she say? Was she talking about that fight I had three days ago? Is she really refusing, after all these years, to let me try to justify myself?

In other words, what sounds natural depends on the story that you are trying to tell and the characters you are trying to depict. Language does not operate in a contextual vacuum.

Comment: The speaker is known as a calm guy and not someone who gets himself into fights. He doesn't understand why a girl he's dating hasn't returned his calls for a few days and wonders if it has anything to do with him being in that fight.

Comment: Given that context, your dialogue seems realistic